# Get header status code from stream_get_meta_data array

Tags: php, regex, http, stream, http-headers

The function `stream_get_meta_data` returns header as an array like this:

```
Array
(
[timed_out] => 
[blocked] => 1
[eof] => 
[wrapper_data] => Array
    (
        [0] => HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

I can get the status with `$meta['wrapper_data'][0]` but how can I fetch the status code from the value which would be `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` as explode by `HTTP/1.1` is bad idea? Is the only way to use regexp to get the code? If absolutely yes, how is the regexp to get a 3-digits number beginning with 1,2,3,4,5 only?

Comment: Regular expression for this is very simple. `/[12345]\d\d/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `explode()` seems to be a good idea because the format of the response is always like this by standard.

But you can use a simple regexp to extract this, too:

```
/[12345]\d\d/
```

Comment: bad `bad idea` I meant, is it always HTTP/1.1? what about if this is a different version than 1.1.? I googled and found this trick too: `substr($headers[0], 9, 3);` is it a better way? or still explode or regext is better?

Comment: @user4271704: why ask? It is a simple choice: if your string consists of a fixed substring, and you know there will be a chunk of fixed width after it, `substr` is all you need. A regex is necessary when you absolutely must grab characters of exact type/class/category some number of times, from 0 to *n*. BTW, to match a 3-digit number *starting* with 1 or 2, 3, 4, or 5, you actually need `/(?<!\d)[12345]\d\d(?!\d)/`. Ahmad, please fix your answer.

Comment: I am not good in regexp, please explain what is the difference of your regexp with the one in answer `/[12345]\d\d/` ?

Comment: And how to get the status message after the code number, e.g. OK, Forbidden etc.? How to parse the entire string to get the message?

Comment: This works fine until someone claims HTTP/1.123 or has a 3-digit number in their status description.

Answer (score 0):

Since the HTTP wrapper follows redirects by default and that will append several HTTP responses to the wrapper_data array, you both need a stricter regexp that won't trigger on all kinds of headers and to iterate through all lines. And I'd recommend against ignoring statuscodes beginning with 6-9, as there is no way to know how HTTP might evolve in the future. Try this:

```
$result = array();
foreach ($responsemeta['wrapper_data'] as $headerline) {
    if (preg_match('/^HTTP\/(\d+\.\d+)\s+(\d+)\s*(.+)?$/', $headerline, $result)) {
        $http_version = $result[1];
        $http_statuscode = $result[2];
        $http_statusstring = $result[3];
    }
}
```